# android: getting the id of the views shown on layout that is being shown as an alert box on another layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to show an alert box of some particular layout on which i have used some textviews and imageviews and imagebuttons. Now my problem is this when i get the id of the imageviews and imagebuttons that are to be put on the alertbox it is returned null.
How shall i resolve this issue?
Can anyone help me over this?

Thanks& Regards

Comment: Can you provide some code of calling `AlertDialog` and how you try to get ids

Comment: post ur code, ur problem is related to getting view id from an inflated layout

Answer (score 0):

i know the answer already)
instead of using

```
loginEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameEdit);
```

in the onCreate method use

```
loginEdit=(EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.usernameEdit);
```

where you inflate your view